# How to install Ubuntu on an usb-drive on a computer that has windows 11 installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, grub

I have a windows 11 system from which I want to boot an ubuntu live-stick. From the stick, I want to install ubuntu on another usb-drive. The windows partition and bootloader should stay untouched.
I installed it explicitly setting grub on the usb-drive. Still it managed to erase the bootloader on the primary drive. How to avoid this without unplugging the primary windows drive?

Comment: It installed Grub in the internal drive, as usual and irrespective of your selection (it's a known behavior) but it DIDN'T erase any other. Your Windows bootloader is still there as can be booted directly just by changing the boot order in the firmware. Unless you really need the installation to be portable I STRONGLY suggest you keep things as they are and manage it via UEFI settings. Doing otherwise isn't trivial.

Comment: When unplugging the newly newly installed USB drive and just start the normal windows installation, it spawns a grub console. How can this be normal behavior?

Comment: It is normal and expected if "Ubuntu" is selected at the OS selection in UEFI > Boot menu. Again, you need to familiarize yourself with your own firmware and that *before* installing OSes and particularly dual-boot.

Comment: Most systems use F12, but you have to check your manual to know which is UEFI boot menu. Should be same key you used to boot Ubuntu live installer. Ubuntu now is using a new installer, subiquity. But Ubiquity installer has had this bug for years. If you want external drive to be portable, you have to have boot loader on it, and boot it like live installer, not an Ubuntu entry. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 You have to have an ESP - efi system partition on external drive.

Comment: @ChanganAuto enlighten me

Comment: The previous comment (by a great expert) did just that.

Comment: why not stay live with casper-rw persistent partition?